# Filter By Key in ng-repeat in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm looping through some objects like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="choiceID in inputs[field.$id]">
    <span ng-repeat="(key, choice) in submission.savedChoices | filter:{key:choiceID}">
        {{key}}
        {{choice}}
    </span>
</div>
```

As you can see I'm trying to filter by the key in the `(key, value)` pair, but it's throwing a syntax error, what is the correct way to do this?

Comment: can you show your full code, so it will be easy to debug, if i remove `ng-repeat="choiceID in inputs[field.$id]"` and give fixed choiceID it is working for me, for checking `ng-repeat="choiceID in inputs[field.$id]"` can you post your full code.

Comment: Your question is quite unclear. If you want to filter by key then simply use key as expression.

Answer (score 0):

Try using ng-if:

```
    <div ng-repeat="choiceID in inputs[field.$id]">
      <span ng-repeat="(key, choice) in submission.savedChoices" ng-if="key==choiceID">
          {{key}}
          {{choice}}
      </span>
    </div>
```